# How to get events to not interfere with each other

Tags: jquery

I am curious how to get jQuery events not to interfere with each other. For instance, in my code below I want the button text to turn white when I mouse over it, and turn back black when my mouse leaves the button. When I click the button, I want it to turn blue. It works, to a point

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#food-roulette, #kwik-pix, #crypto, #realtalk").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).css('color', 'white');
      });

    $("#food-roulette, #kwik-pix, #crypto, #realtalk").mouseout(function(){
      $(this).css('color', 'black');
      });

      $(document).on('click','#food-roulette, #kwik-pix, #crypto, #realtalk' ,function(){
        $(this).css("color","blue");
      });    


});
```

The problem comes that as soon as I click the button and it turns blue, if I move my mouse the mouseover/mouseout functions take over.

I want to make sure that when I click a button, it stays blue. And once I click a new button, then the newly clicked button stays blue, and the previously clicked one can now be turned white/black by mouseover/mouseout.

Can anyone assist me in how I keep track of states and/or keep events from overlapping.

Comment: You could `.addClass('clicked')` on the click event and have the `clicked` class defined as `color: blue !important` in your css

Comment: Ok that make sense, make a CSS for a specific class and then set whatever button that was clicked to give it its CSS properties. How would I then go about detecting a previously clicked button (if any) so I can remove the newly assigned class.

Answer (score 1):

So I would do something like this

```
<script>
    var els = '#food-roulette, #kwik-pix, #crypto, #realtalk';

    $(document).on('mouseenter', els, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked') {
            $(this).css('color', '#FFFFFF');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('mouseleave', els, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked') {
            $(this).css('color', '#000000');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', els, function() {
        $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });    
</script>
```

And don't forget to define `.clicked {color: #0000FF !important;}` in your CSS.

Also, I prefer hex codes to words for colours. eg `#000000` for black, `#FFFFFF` for white and `#0000FF` for blue.

Edit: added a check for the clicked class on mouse enter/leave. Also, you could use .hover as the other user suggested.

Comment: Actually i just noticed the if statements cause the button to keep the white color even if they weren't being hovered over after clicking another button Removing the if statements fixes that, but if I add some more properties without the if statements then of course I get other errors.

Comment: The dirty workaround was to set the css color to black just before adding the class '.clicked',basically Im changing the color twice.

Answer (score 0):

You need a var.

```
var clicked = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#food-roulette, #kwik-pix, #crypto, #realtalk").mouseenter(function(){
        if (!clicked) $(this).css('color', 'white');
    });
    $("#food-roulette, #kwik-pix, #crypto, #realtalk").mouseleave(function(){
        if (!clicked) $(this).css('color', 'black');
    });
    $(document).on('click','#food-roulette, #kwik-pix, #crypto, #realtalk' ,function(){
        clicked=1;
        $(this).css("color","blue");
    });    
});
```

It's proper for you to use `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` event. So .css() will trigger once when mouse is entering or leaving element, not like `mouseover` that will make css change triggered all the time when hovering.

**Just for information**

You can also using the official shortcut for `mouseenter` & `mouseleave` events. It's called `hover`.

```
$("#food-roulette, #kwik-pix, #crypto, #realtalk").hover(function(){
    //when mouse enter
    if (!clicked) $(this).css('color', 'white');
},function(){
    //when mouse leave
    if (!clicked) $(this).css('color', 'black');
});
```